# Threads Using Managed Objects Between Contexts

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am at that point where I am losing hair on this so I figured I'd reach out to the great minds here who have had experience using Objective C with Threads and core data. I am having issues with managed objects inserted in on thread in a NSPrivateQueue Context being accessed from the main thread. So at a high level I am using AFNetworking to generate a thread to make requests to retrieve JSON data from a server and then insert the values into my persistent store core data.  After this is done I have another thread for downloading some binary data using AFNetworking as well. I have set up 2 managed contexts for this as shown below:

```
(NSManagedObjectContext *)masterManagedContext {
if (_masterManagedContext != nil) {
    return _masterManagedContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coord = [self coordinator];
if (coord != nil) {
    _masterManagedContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
     _masterManagedContext.stalenessInterval = 0.0;
    [_masterManagedContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [_masterManagedContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coord];
    }];

}
return _masterManagedContext;
}


// Return the NSManagedObjectContext to be used in the background during sync
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)backgroundManagedContext {
if (_backgroundManagedContext != nil) {
 return _backgroundManagedContext;
 }

NSManagedObjectContext *masterContext = [self masterManagedContext];
if (masterContext != nil) {
    _backgroundManagedContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
     _backgroundManagedContext.stalenessInterval = 0.0;
    [_backgroundManagedContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [_backgroundManagedContext setParentContext:masterContext];
    }];
}

return _backgroundManagedContext;
```

}

As is shown above I am using a child context and the parent context. When I make I call to fetch the json data I have something like below:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        //Initially delete all records in table. This will change
         [[Singleton sharedInstance]removeEntityObjects:className];

           for (int x=0; x < [JSON count]; x++) {
                NSMutableDictionary *curDict = [JSON objectAtIndex:x];
                   [[CoreDatam sharedinstance] insertEmployeesWithDictionary:curDict];

                }else  {
                    /* do nothing */
                }
            }
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error,id JSON) {

        [delegate performSelector:@selector(didNotCompleteSync:) withObject:className];
    }];

    [operations addObject:operation];
}    

[self.AFClient enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    NSLog(@"Currenlty downloaded table data %d of %d!",numberOfCompletedOperations,totalNumberOfOperations);

} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {

    if (_syncInProgress) {
          [[CoreDatam sharedInstance]updateEmpForId];



           [self downloadAllFiles];
    }
}];
```

}`

for the insert function I have something like below:

```
 insertEmployeesWithDictionary:curDict {

[[self backgroundManagedContext]performBlockAndWait:^{
Employee *emp = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:[self backgroundManagedContext]];

/* Issues saving null into core data based on type.*/
[emp setFirst:[dictCopy objectForKey:@"first"]];
[emp setLast:[dictCopy objectForKey:@"last"]];


    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL saved;
    saved = [[self backgroundManagedContext] save:&error];
    if (!saved) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self saveMasterContext];

}];
```

}

The issue is below where I am trying to access the managed objects in the method that is in the completion block above:

```
updateEmpId {
[self.backgroundManagedContext performBlockAndWait:^{
     NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                 [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"last" ascending:YES]]];

    myEmps = [self.backgroundManagedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

 for (Employee *moEmp in myEmps) {
        [[self backgroundManagedContext]refreshObject:moEmp mergeChanges:YES];
        moEmp.photo = @'default.pic';
 }
                NSError *saveError = nil;
                if (![self.backgroundManagedContext save:&saveError]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }

            [self saveMasterContext];
```

}

The issue is that I am getting very inconsistent behavior when looking at the managed objects that are modified in the main thread. Is it still necessary to pass managed objectIds when using a parent child context relation? if so how can I do so for the above example? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `NSManagedObjectIDs` or re-fetch in the main thread context, yeah. If you pass object IDs, get the IDs from the background context after saving the new Employee objects, and use `existingObjectWithID:error:` in the parent context to instantiate them there. Or just re-do the fetch request from your `updateEmpId` code block in the `masterManagedContext`.

Comment: So even though I am using the same context in a the AFNetworking thread and the main thread. I would still need to pass in object ids between both methods. Do you have an example of how to do this for the above example? Just trying to get an idea as I have not had to work with coredata and managed objects on different threads. Thanks.